# Delete the tag [website] and its synonyms

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The current SO tag [website](/questions/tagged/website) (and its synonym [websites](/questions/tagged/websites)) should be removed from SO entirely. They currently serve no useful purpose for a question (all relevant questions have almost always been also tagged with a more-related web technology tag, such as [html](/questions/tagged/html), [php](/questions/tagged/php), or [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)), and simply serve to waste a tag space on a question that could be used to hold a more relevant tag. This tag conveys no further information to someone reading the question; by seeing one of the more relevant tags, the reader is already made aware that the question utilizes the web.

Its description is simply a definition of a website from Wikipedia:

> A website is a collection of related web pages containing images,
>   videos or other digital assets. A website is hosted on at least one
>   web server, accessible via a network such as the Internet or a private
>   local area network through an Internet address also called URL.

Comment: Really, what purpose does it have?

Comment: The only purpose it seems to have is as a honeypot for questions that can mostly be closed and deleted. I've been going through them for a few days.